# SQL table Column defaut to Nullable

Tags: sql

Is Nullable set as default for the column? So if you create new column in the table and not set something like nullable="true", should it be default to nullable? And the auto generated value the column will be Null?

Comment: What **concrete** RDBMS are you talking about?

Comment: Imo it depends on RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you create new column, if you don't specify NOT NULL as below, then column is populated with null value as a default.

created_by VARCHAR2(50) **NOT NULL**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the RDBMS you're using, but in SQL Server:

Unless the field you're creating is the primary key for the table or you specify otherwise, it defaults to NULLs allowed and the default value will be NULL.